# jQuery created class inside script

Tags: javascript, jquery, class, event-handling, dom-manipulation

I want to click a paragraph and show something, which has a class created inside script tag but I couldn't make it clickable. Can anyone help how to do it?

Below is part of my code..

```
$('#three-star').click(function(){
    var id=$('#elements-container').children().length+1;
    $('#elements-container').append('<p id="'+id+'" class = "edit">Type your question here</p>');
});

$('p.edit').click(function(){               
    $('#editor').show();
});
```

How can I do `show()` when I click on "Type your question here"?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you remember to wrap in `.ready()`?

Comment: I updated Answer with fiddle

Comment: also added fiddle in my answer!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [**event delegation**](http://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/)

```
$('#elements-container').on("click" , 'p.edit',function(){               
            $('#editor').show();
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

Working fiddle [**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/3tpS3/)

Use following

```
 $("p.edit").on("click",function(){               
     $('#editor').show();
 });
```

Because `$('p.edit').click(function(){` This doesnt support New Dynamically created content.So use `on` event.

Answer (score 0):

**[Working fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/MYy72/177/)**
Create the paragraph dynamically and add event to the element.

```
var comment = "Type your question here.";
var newParagraph = document.createElement('p');
newParagraph.textContent = comment;
newParagraph.id = 3;
newParagraph.onclick = function () {
    $('#qs_div').show();
};
```

Answer (score 0):

An `event listener` can be delegated to a parent element.

```
$('#container').on('click', '.edit', function(event) {
    // do something
});
```

When someone clicks on the edit link, the event bubbles up the DOM and is caught by the listener.

There is some more information on event bubbling [here](http://api.jquery.com/on/)